# How to shrink a git repository by removing all outputs from all Jupyter notebooks in the history

Tags: git, jupyter

I'd like to shrink a git repository by removing all outputs from every Jupyter notebook in the repository's history. Is this even possible?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218382/21891079) to see how you can keep the output from being saved in the repository in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible using `git filter-repo`.

1. Install [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-install-it)
2. Get a clean clone of your repository, and make sure you keep a backup in case something goes wrong.
3. Go to the repository's root directory, and run the following command:

```sh
git filter-repo --blob-callback '
import json
try:
    notebook = json.loads(blob.data)
    if "cells" in notebook:
        for cell in notebook["cells"]:
            if "outputs" in cell:
                cell["outputs"] = []
        blob.data = (json.dumps(notebook, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1,
                                sort_keys=True) + "\n").encode("utf-8")
except json.JSONDecodeError as ex:
    pass
except UnicodeDecodeError as ex:
    pass
'
```

This command will call the Python code for every blob in the history, and it will try to parse it as JSON. If that works and returns a dict with a `"cells"` key, then we're (almost certainly) dealing with a Jupyter notebook, and we can go through the cells and replace the outputs with an empty array. The code then uses `json.dumps()` to dump back the notebook to file, replacing the blob's previous data.

I tried this on a repository with many notebooks, about 200MB large, and it shrunk down to 20MB. I found this quite nice so I thought I'd share.