# How to clear Jupyter Notebook's output and metadata when using git commit?

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook

The output and metadata is not for code reviewing and it is annoying if committed. How to clear Jupyter Notebook's output and metadata when using git commit?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71215105/21891079) to see how you can remove output and metadata retroactively.

Answer (score 17):

[github post](https://gist.github.com/33eyes/431e3d432f73371509d176d0dfb95b6e)

[similar approach in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004619/15326444)

the answer is based on the previous 2 posts.

My approach includes cleaning metadata at the same time.

Add this to your local .git/config

```
[filter "strip-notebook-output"]
clean = "jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR"
```

Create a .gitattributes file in your directory with notebooks, with this content:

```
*.ipynb filter=strip-notebook-output
```

Comment: I think this runs every time you touch git in your repo (like `git status` even), so be careful!

Comment: Git filters are usually only run on checkout and staging. The clean filter is run when staging. They can be run with `git status` under certain conditions. See [Why does 'git status' run filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935511/21891079).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command-line json processor `jq` to perform this task notably quicker than with `nbconvert`. This [blog post](https://timstaley.co.uk/posts/making-git-and-jupyter-notebooks-play-nice/) shows how to get rid of metadata, outputs and execution counts via this command:

```
jq --indent 1 \
    '
    (.cells[] | select(has("outputs")) | .outputs) = []
    | (.cells[] | select(has("execution_count")) | .execution_count) = null
    | .metadata = {"language_info": {"name":"python", "pygments_lexer": "ipython3"}}
    | .cells[].metadata = {}
    ' 01-parsing.ipynb
```

You could also modify to just clean a specific part of the output, such as execution counts (recursively wherever they occur in the json), and then add this as a git filter:

```
[filter "nbstrip"]
    clean = jq --indent 1 '(.. |."execution_count"? | select(. != null)) = null'
    smudge = cat
```

And add the following to `~/.config/git/attributes` to have the filter applied globally to all your local repos:

```
*.ipynb filter=nbstripout
```

There are some more ideas in this thread [How to clear Jupyter Notebook's output in all cells from the Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908319/how-to-clear-jupyter-notebooks-output-in-all-cells-from-the-linux-terminal/74104683#74104683). There is also [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout) which is made for this purpose, but it's a bit slower.

Comment: Tried jq, didn't work in filiter -- nbstripout worked first time, and appears more light-weight than nbconvert.

Comment: Using `jq` worked for me and it is fast and flexible. Best solution if you need to adjust what parts of the metadata (notebook by per cell) that you want to keep/exclude.