# What is the "codemirror_mode" key in notebooks and how can it be customized?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbformat

I am writing a [git filter for Jupyter notebook output and metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73218304/21891079) and I would like to learn more about the `metadata.language_info.codemirror_mode` key so that I can make an informed decision about how to handle it in the filter. A good answer will explain...

- How this value is used by the notebook
- What valid values it can be set to (some examples)

Relevant meta question: [To what extent are "What does [thing] do" questions OK to ask?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424444/to-what-extent-are-what-does-thing-do-questions-ok-to-ask)

### What I have found so far

- The [nbformat documentation](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html) has the following description: "The name of the codemirror mode to use [optional]". This doesn't say what names are possible...
- The above page links to [the official JSON schema for the Jupyter Notebook format](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/blob/main/nbformat/v4/nbformat.v4.schema.json) which has the following:

  ```
  "codemirror_mode": {
    "description": "The codemirror mode to use for code in this language.",
    "oneOf": [{ "type": "string" }, { "type": "object" }]
  }
  ```

  Not sure what the `string` or `object` is supposed to be...
- Searching "codemirror" leads me to [the CodeMirror user manual and reference guide](https://web.mit.edu/xavid/Public/bazki/lib/ext/codemirror/manual.html) which as this to say about modes

  > `mode (string or object)`

  This matches! That's great!

  > The mode to use. When not given, this will default to the first mode that was loaded. It may be a string, which either simply names the mode or is a MIME type associated with the mode. Alternatively, it may be an object containing configuration options for the mode, with a name property that names the mode (for example {name: "javascript", json: true}). The demo pages for each mode contain information about what configuration parameters the mode supports. You can ask CodeMirror which modes and MIME types are loaded with the CodeMirror.listModes and CodeMirror.listMIMEs functions.

Still not sure exactly what is permissible and how it affects notebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`codemirror_mode` key](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/blob/dda25ef6565a33cef9096c283a47cc3fa8b96f91/nbformat/v4/nbformat.v4.schema.json#L37-L40) in Jupyter notebooks is used for syntax highlighting: it determines the styling (color, font, etc.) of various elements of the code (like keywords, strings, comments) based on the language or format.
And it assists in code editing by providing language-specific features like auto-indentation, bracket matching, and code folding.

Valid values for `codemirror_mode` are one of those two:

- **String**: A simple string that names the mode or specifies a MIME type associated with the mode.
  Example: `"python"`, `"text/x-c++src"`, `"application/json"` (see "[CodeMirror language modes](https://codemirror.net/5/mode/)").
- **Object**: An object with configuration options for the mode, including a `name` property that names the mode and other optional settings.
  Example: `{name: "javascript", json: true}` for JSON data in JavaScript.

How it affects notebooks:

- When a specific `codemirror_mode` is set, it tailors the code cell's behavior to the specified language or format, improving readability and ease of coding.
- It does not affect the execution of the code, but only enhances the user interface and interaction.